# One to many mapping in Zend Framwork 2 with doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I am trying to make a page where i handle my invoces. I have the invoice data in one tables and the invoice rows in another table. The tables looks as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Invoices` (
  `I_Id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `I_Number` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `I_ClientId` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `I_ExtraText` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`I_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `InvoiceRows` (
  `IR_Id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `IR_InvoiceId` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `IR_Price` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `IR_Vat` smallint(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `IR_Quantity` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `IR_Text` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`IR_Id`),
  KEY `IR_InvoiceId` (`IR_InvoiceId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Here is my mapping:

```
class Invoice {
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Row", mappedBy="invoice" ,cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $rows;
}

class Row {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Invoice", inversedBy="rows", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="IR_InvoiceId", referencedColumnName="I_Id")
     **/
    private $invoice;
}
```

I have been trying to follow the example at the [doctrine docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) on how to setup a One-To-Many, Bidirectional mapping. This is then connect with Zend Framework 2 and [form collections](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.form.collections.html). Pulling data works very good. I get all the rows of each invoice.

My Problem is when i want to write back to the database and save my changes. When i try to save i get the following error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO
MVIT_ADM__InvoiceRows (IR_InvoiceId, IR_Price, IR_Vat, IR_Quantity,
IR_Text) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params
{"1":null,"2":320,"3":0,"4":1,"5":"Learning your dog to sit"}:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column
'IR_InvoiceId' cannot be null
```

What have i done wrong? When checking the data from the post value is not empty.

Edit: Full source can be found at [Github](https://github.com/riceri/MvitInvoice)

Comment: As you can see from the error message, the value for `IR_InvoiceId` is `null` which according to your `class Row` is not allowed to be `null`. You can do two things: 1) set `IR_InvoiceId` to nullable or 2) make sure that you give the new entity a `IR_InvoiceId`. I suggest the latter of course. However to see why it is `null` I would need to see the controller code where you create the new row entity and persist it

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, and can be seen in this line of your `InvoiceRows` table create statement ` `IR_InvoiceId` int(10) NOT NULL,`

Comment: When i check the data from the forms that are in the entity InvoiceId has a value so do >$this->getEntityManager()->persist($invoice);
>$this->getEntityManager()->flush();
That value gets cleared but the others dosen't.

Comment: It also tries to make a insert and not update. :)

Comment: Sounds like your Form-Code made be more interesting then ;) The setup of the entities looks valid to me...

Comment: The full source can be found at github: https://github.com/riceri/MvitInvoice

Answer (score 0):

It seems IR_InvoiceId null, it expect the Id of Invoices (I_Id) value, so make sure while you are inserting the data in InvoiceRows table then here pass the Invoices (I_Id) value as IR_InvoiceId as you mention table relation..

Best Of Luck!
Saran ﻿